# Typescript doesn't see return values from try/catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a function that does some database operations. The implementation is wrapped in a `try/catch` block. E.g

```
async function update({id, ...changes}): Promise<IUserResult> {
 try {
  //code implementation here
  return updatedUser
 } catch(error) {
    console.error
 }
}
```

Typescript compiler always throws an error that I return undefined. I know this is so because I don't return any value explicitly from the function block itself but from the `try/catch` block. How do I go about this? I am just learning typescript and I was wondering how to get the return values to match the function return type, in this case, the `IUserResult`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You return a value from the `try` but not the `catch`. If you’re not going to return something you’d need to update the function’s signature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Typescript wants a valid return type for all cases, but you don't have any return in case of exception.

You need to return something in your catch (or maybe finally) block or make return type like Promise<IUserResult|void>

Comment: It seems that I can return an invalid type in my `catch` block though. If I move the invalid return type outside of the catch block it catches the invalid return type. I tried with a more trivial type and it catches it. Maybe it's because both of the types I'm using extend the same base type without any change in implementation. Oddly though when I move that type out of the catch block it then fails. So this may be a bug then? 